# Can I use a relative path name with javascript's window.open() function?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I want to open a file in a popup window.  The file must be located in the same directory that houses my other "html" files that my web server uses.  Unfortunately, it has to work with the IE6 browser.

I thought that it would work if I just used "name.html" like this:

```
window.open('name.html', '_blank');
```

but it doesn't ( I get "Page can't be found').

Can I actually use a pathname relative to the web server root directory?
If not, is there another method I could use?

Kind Regards!

Comment: Should be `window.open('/name.html', '_blank');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a url and just the filename is not a url. So specify it like you would the href value in a link: http://somedomain/filename.html

Comment: But href values can be relative, whereas `window.open` needs an absolute path.